# error : this version information could not be downloaded

Tags: python, ide

I have downloaded the eric ide for python. when ever i try to open the ide the error above said keep popping up on my screen 
please help

Comment: I get the same cryptic error.

Comment: Same here. It flashes the host it looks for "eric-ide.python-projects.org" just before the version information popup.